# not able to understand scene position importance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to write some sample code of three.js where i have a plane and i want that plane to rotate around.

This is my camera:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1,  1000);
camera.position.set(50, 50, 60);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

and this is my plane:

```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(70, 30, 1, 1);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: green });
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
scene.add(plane);
```

i have other code too but this is my render and animationframe code:

```
renderScene();

function cameraUpdate() {
  camera.position.x = cameraRadius * Math.cos(step);
  camera.position.z = cameraRadius * Math.sin(step);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function renderScene() {
 //make update to position, rotation of objects in the scene
  step += 0.05;
  cameraUpdate();
  requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

My question is that inside cameraUpdate function if dont put

```
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

the rotation become very wierd and when i put this inside cameraUpdate, i get rotation of the plane in own axis which is desired !!!

My question is

1. what does scene.position mean
2. Why do i need to make camera lookat at every animation frame? i dont understand how its value get changed when camera is rotated

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the plane to rotate on its own, you should just use `plane.rotation.y += 0.1` on each frame, or something simple like that. What you’re doing instead is that you’re making the camera move around in circles around the plane. Think of it as walking in a circle around a coffee table. If you keep your head looking forward, you won’t see the table as you walk past it. That’s what `camera.lookAt()` fixes. It makes the camera look at a point in space. You can [read about it in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=perspe#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt).

`scene.position` is by default at `(0, 0, 0)` so it’s just another way of telling the camera to look at the center of the scene.